# How can I tell Z3 where to start when solving a formula?

Tags: z3, smt

I am currently dealing with a situation where the assertions given to Z3 contain a large number of inequalities and equalities. They are dependent on each other in a way that it is most efficient to start solving the formula by assigning values to the variables used in the equalities.

Is there a way to alter the heuristics of Z3 such that the solver always chooses to "start" at these formulas?

My guess would be to use a tactic which initially processes a goal containing the mentioned equalities. It would then continue with the other assertions, restarting the whole process if necessary.

However, I'm not sure how to go about implementing this - how can I create custom goals from sets of formulas?

Answer (score 0):

You can try asserting the first set of formulas you want, then issue check-sat, issue the next set, issue check-sat; repeat as necessary. You can also use push-pop to go back to these points if you want.

By issuing multiple check-sats this way, you would be forcing the solver to explore the formulas you asserted up to that point. Whether this would actually achieve what you want of course depends on exactly what your formulas look like and how much the solver can derive at each check-sat call.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that!